# how to find the next span with a class not nested in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      {{$comment->user->name}} said <small class="text-primary">{{$comment->updated_at->diffForHumans()}}</small>
                      @if($comment->user_id == Auth::user()->id || Auth::user()->id == 2)
                      <a id="{{ $comment->id }}" class="pull-right comment_edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                      <a id="{{ $comment->id }}" style="margin-right: 10px;" class="pull-right comment_delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                      @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                      <span class="comment_textarea">{{$comment->comment}}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

When the button edit is clicked, I would like to get the text in the span with class "comment_textarea".

I tried with jquery to use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.comment_edit', function () {
 comment_comment = $(this).closest("comment_textarea").text();
 console.log(comment_comment);
});
```

But it doesn't return me anything. I tried also with next but it is the same.

I guess this is because it is in another div than where the button sits so how can I get the value from the next span with this class when it is not nested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next with find function 
Let me know if it helped you or not

```
$(document).on('click', '.comment_edit', function () {
 comment_comment = $(this).parent().next().find(".comment_textarea").text();
 console.log(comment_comment);
});
```

Comment: @Richard sorry bro. I 've added parent method now. Can you check again? I've updated my answer

Comment: You re a star :). It works. Thanks for such a quick help. I have been trying for 2 hours, I should have come and ask faster, my bad :).

Comment: @Richard Thanks for your kind words. And You are always welcome on SO :)

Comment: @Richard Bro can you mark my answer as correct answer :)